# Type mismatch: cannot convert MyClass<E> to MyClass<E>

Tags: java, generics, inner-classes

There is something I am missing about generics and/or inner classes.  I want to write a specialized tree class, with a specialized iterator.  How can class FooTree have an iterator that returns successive nodes of type FooTree rather than node values of type V?  The class starts:

```
public class FooTree<V>
   private final V value;
   private FooTree<V> left;
   private FooTree<V> right;
```

I made the Iterator class an inner class since nobody else will care about it.  The factory method defined in FooTree to get an iterator is:

```
public Iterator<FooTree<V>> preorderIterator() {
    return this.new PreorderIterator<FooTree<V>>;
}
```

Since next() must return a V, as declared in the interface, I added nextNode() to get around the return type.  The inner class starts:

```
private class PreorderIterator<V> implements Iterator<V> {
   private FooTree<V> current;  
   . . .
   public FooTree<V> nextNode() {
      current = FooTree.this;                        **
```

I get this wonderful compiler error:
`Type mismatch: cannot convert from ...FooTree<V> to ...FooTree<V>`   (both are the same package)

Eh wot!?
  I can make it compile by adding a cast:   current = (FooTree)FooTree.this;
But why should I have to in the first place?
Is it trying to be "smart" and figuring the first V might be different from the second V?

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Try making your declaration:

```
private class PreorderIterator implements Iterator<V>
```

The `<V>` in your inner class is unnecessary, and in this case, unhelpful.

What's actually happening is that the `<V>` in `PreorderIterator<V>` is "shadowing" the `<V>` from your outer class, so that although they look like they're the same type parameter, they're actually different parameters that happen to have the same name.

Comment: Thanks!  Once I give up the preconception that the inner class needs to be explicitly parametric too, all the errors and hints I had gotten while exploring fall into place.